# How does SSL certificate benefit a public informational website?

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate

One networking expert posted a video today in Facebook saying that a government website (which is a subdomain of `kerala.gov.in`) has no SSL certificate installed. That website is actually just for informative purpose. I mean displaying some information to the public, with no confidential data (passwords, contact information, sessions, payments, etc.) communicated between the client and the server.

So I commented that it is not mandatory for such a simple informative website to have the SSL certificate as there is no confidential information transmitted. But another expert replied to my comment with an insult. I know that I am not an expert and I have limited knowledge. And I know that Google Chrome and some browsers will show `not secured` in the addressbar if the website doesn't have an SSL and this has forced many website owners to install the SSL even when they are having just a single webpage with some informative text only.

So I deleted my comment and messaged him through chat, to learn about why he posted an insult/objection to my comment. His response was:

> SSL is an absolutely necessary way when a Government site wants to
>   show its domain and URL. Because, anyone can host a site and a domain
>   (or spoof a domain) without a SSL.
>
> It is not just about personal data or business transactions. It is
>   more about the authenticity of the site.

I told him that the TLD `gov.in` is not available for the public to purchase, so if someone sees the website address with this TLD, they can easily identify that its a government website. And he replied this:

> SSL is important. Regarddless of being a subdomain of any gov domain.
>
> In internet, there is nothing like 'just some information' and
>   'serious information'.
>
> For eg. It may take very little time for me to access the internals of
>   that site. It's a flower game for any experienced hacker.
>
> SSL also make it safer and easier to allow authenticated remote
>   maintenance.

So, what I understood from his response is that, the SSL certificate will let the people know that its an authentic website. But actually the use of SSL certificate is to encrypt the communication, isn't it? Though it does domain ownership verification, should it really be mandatory to have the SSL installed for a website that just displays some content?

Btw, the state data center where these government websites are hosted, has strict firewalls and rules, which would prevent remote maintenance of the website. That is, inorder to do any maintenance of the website, you need to be physically present in the data center. I don't have personal experience with these servers, but heard only through some articles.

Am a bit confused here regarding his comments. Kindly shed some light. It would really help me understand & learn more. Because two articles which I referred to double check this info, wasn't providing any extra info other than what I said to him.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is far too broad to answer. "Government" is too generic and vague of a term.

Comment: @joeqwerty, Its a website of kerala government, where they display information about the weather, precautions to be taken during severe weather conditions, etc. Let me know if you need any other information. Or else, if this question doesn't fit in this community, please feel free to move to the respective community. Thank you.

Comment: This is quite a broad topic. However, without EV certificates, everything TLS guarantees (to a degree, under certain conditions) is that the traffic between the server and client can't be read or altered. There is no implied guarantee about an actual identity behind the server or that it isn't compromised.

Comment: Explaining the technical side of the benefits of HTTPS extending beyond just adding encryption is very possible, but I suppose the problem is "is it mandatory for a government site" bit?  Maybe if it was rephrased in terms of "how does it benefit an public informational site" or something along those lines?

Comment: In my view, a disaster prevention site should be kept as secure as possible. Imagine someone manages to alter the traffic in transit and changes a recommendation that in case of a flooding, location X should be used  as shelter to location Y, that in reality is a deathtrap during a flood.

Comment: At a minimum, the government involved should be identified. In the US, SSL is essentially required for *all* web sites. You mileage will vary when you travel outside the US.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, thank you. I have rephrased my question.

Comment: @Sven, I was being told by some guys and some articles that the servers in the government data center has so many restrictions and firewalls. What you said is a possibility, but I don't know whether they will display the locations of the shelters or safe houses.

Comment: @DougO'Neal, I was talking about the website of a state government of India.

Comment: Certificates now offer more than simply encryption for data in transit and trust of the preventing server. They can go beyond that with the likes of Organisation Validation and Extended Validation to actually be a meaningful indicator that the person who is publishing said content, has actually done so, and is a real entitity. Its not just about encryption and server trust anymore. Its inter-personal trust & verification.

Comment: @tomstephens89, thank you. But that's not the basic SSL, isn't it? A basic SSL (say for example, Positive SSL from Comodo) would merely verifies the ownership of the domain and helps in doing the encrypted communication isn't it? What the other guy (the expert who I talked to) was talking about, was the basic SSL.

Comment: I am  speaking from experience in the US government so this may not strictly apply. The SSL certificate confers an authenticity to the source as well as protecting the content so I would always enable SSL whenever possible. SSL certificates are inexpensive (compared to the total cost of ownership of the site), so go ahead and get an SSL certificate though the official government channels if possible or through less official means if necessary.

Comment: @DougO'Neal, thanks for sharing your thoughts. Actually the website is not done by me. I just commented on the video which an expert posted in Facebook where he was criticizing it for not having the SSL installed. And then another expert insulted me for my comment, where I mentioned that its just an informative website containing some text and SSL is not mandatory. So I was like, I need to figure this out today itself. Because if am wrong, I shouldn't be repeating my mistake again. Instead I should correct it and learn!

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran yes you are correct a standard SSL cert only proves domain ownership. To be honest, if certain email accounts and access to the web server have been compromised anyway, this proves nothing. But its is a start and does provide encryption. Standard SSL certs are in no way an indicator of a trusted authority.

Comment: @tomstephens89, thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: https://www.troyhunt.com/heres-why-your-static-website-needs-https/